Проблема с отображением текста в SFML C++
Я создаю свой простой проект и у меня возникла проблема. У меня есть класс Menu:
class Menu
{   
private:
    sf::Text    m_text;
public:
    Menu();
    ~Menu();
    void draw(sf::RenderWindow& window);
    void InitText(sf::Text& text, float xpos, float ypos, sf::String str, int size_font=150, 
    sf::Color menu_text_color = sf::Color::White, int bord = 0, sf::Color border_color = sf::Color::Black);
};

И вот его реализация:
Menu::Menu()
{
    m_text.setFont(fonts::fontVideoType);
    InitText(m_text, 500, 500, "2Test");
}

Menu::~Menu()
{}

void Menu::draw(sf::RenderWindow& window)
{
    window.draw(m_text);
}

void Menu::InitText(sf::Text& text,
                    float xpos, 
                    float ypos, 
                    sf::String str, 
                    int size_font, 
                    sf::Color menu_text_color, 
                    int bord, 
                    sf::Color border_color)
{
    text.setCharacterSize(size_font);
    text.setPosition(xpos, ypos);
    text.setString(str);
    text.setFillColor(menu_text_color);
    text.setOutlineThickness(bord);
    text.setOutlineColor(border_color);
}

Далее в main я вызываю функцию загрузки шрифта, создаю экземпляр класса Menu и в цикле вызываю метод .draw() этого класса. Вот часть кода функции:
fonts::loadFont();
sf::Text tytle;
tytle.setFont(fonts::fontVideoType);
InitText(tytle, sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode().width/100, sf::VideoMode::getDesktopMode().height/100, "Test", 150, sf::Color(237, 147, 0), 3);

Menu menu = Menu();

while (window.isOpen())
{
    sf::Event event;
    while (window.pollEvent(event))
    {
       if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed || sf::Keyboard::isKeyPressed(sf::Keyboard::Escape))
      {
          window.close();
       }
    }

        window.draw(background);
        window.draw(tytle);
        menu.draw(window);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;

Проблема в том, что текст "Test", который я создаю в main выводится без проблем, то есть шрифт загружается и устанавливается корректно. А вот текст "2Test" выводится не корректно, вместо текста один пиксель, хотя по-сути я делаю всё тоже самое, только через класс.

Почему в последнем куске кода InitText вызывается без указания объекта (то есть видимо подразумевается this)? У вас некий класс main тоже наследуется от Menu или что происходит вообще?

Извиняюсь за путаницу. Это функция с таким же названием и реализацией, что и метод в классе Menu. Они полностью идентичны. Я просто пытался убедиться, что она работает вне класса. И да, она работает.

Вот как я смог решить проблему:  я  создал поле m_font в классе Menu и передаю в качестве параметра в конструктор класса Menu ссылку на шрифт Menu menu = Menu(window, fonts::fontVideoType); , далее присваиваю полю значение переданной ссылки  m_font=font и это начинает работать, хотя не понимаю как.
